# Decompiled Dalvik class - not all imports available

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex

I decompiled dex and when browsing one of the classes I noticed that it contains imports from custom namespace like 'ua.blah.blah.ClassName'. When I started searching for it - seems like it is not in the dex file. I tried several tools for dex dumping and none of them helped.

So I'm wondering how is it possible for this apk\dex to work? Where this missing piece can be? It is cleanly not a standard class (like java.blah.blah).

Also I tried to search for DexClassLoader, so that may be it downloads this part from somewhere - no entries found..

Comment: could you post the import statement for the class you can't find?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot due to legislation reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name can be either to one of your ofuscated classes or a library class already ofuscated.

If its not on your source structure then its a jar/aar/gradle dependency.

Check into the build.gradle the packages.
Also, I don't know if it was a jar where it will be after compiled+descompiled.

Comment: Actually obfuscation could be the case.. I just found single obfuscated class there, subclass of Application. Extracted it and compiled into separate apk. But it won't work in debugger - freezes in strange place. Will look at it more tomorrow.

Strange that other classes does not look like obfuscated.

Comment: Proguard has keepnames for some extends View/Activity/Service and some other things